# Salesforce Case Comment update Creator Name

Tags: salesforce, case, salesforce-chatter, salesforce-communities

I am creating case comment using Apex. I am using the following code to add comment:

```
CaseComment cc=new CaseComment();
cc.ParentId=obj.Id;
cc.CreatedById='12323re';
cc.CommentBody='test comment';
insert cc;
```

I am getting the following error on compile time :
Field is not writeable: CaseComment.CreatedById

How can i change the Created by of a Case comment?

Comment: Anshu Kumar - were you able to post the case comment with a different user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case Comment cannot be created by the different user as CreatedById is not a writable field. Salesforce does not allow this for some security reasons.
Temporarily, I have stored the commenter information in the comment body and used the information from the comment body for further use.